# CocoaLumberjack printing each statement 4 times

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoalumberjack

I'm using CocoaLumberjack as the default logging system for a framework I'm developing. I setup the framework as per the instructions on github. I setup the framework to print to the console and Xcode. The problem is, printing to Xcode results in each statement being printed 4 times.

Is this normal? Is there something else I need to fiddle with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that's not normal. You mentioned that you followed the instructions on GitHub, but just to be sure let's rule out the super obvious.

The following lines add extra loggers and should usually be called just once:

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
```

Have you made sure that you're not adding loggers multiple (4) times? Or that you've put the lines in a method that gets called multiple times.

Comment: This may be my problem. I'm putting them in an + (void)initialize method in the main class of my framework.

Comment: I moved it away from the + (void)initialize method and now it's all smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Update: For iOS => 10 there are duplicated logs:
https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/765

Comment: And this only happen on device not simulator, I solved it by simply adding TTYLogger ONLY when initializing DDLog.